# Some of my army camp troops have gone missing for the second time!

Tags: clash-of-clans

My army troops all together can hold 190 troops. I only attack frequently during wars and the rest of the times, I do farming. I've had two experiences where my troops go missing even though I didn't even donate them or use them.

**1st case** (2 weeks back): While I prepared for war, I trained three dragons in my army camp. When the war began, I found out that I have lost a dragon with a couple of giants.

**2nd case** (Recently) : (*Since I donate too much, most of the times my army camps will be full of barbarians and archers. Sometimes a few wizards and rarely I keep giants* .)When I tried to donate 3 giants to my friend, I found out that all of my 14 giants and 3 hog riders have gone missing.

**I have a bad feeling that this might happen the third time also. Does this happen to you? or What should I do to overcome this problem? I love this game so much and need a solution for this problem.**

Comment: Never got troops missing in the way you described. The only time troops went missing were that donated troops never reached their destination (or reached it after over 12 hours).

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason I'm aware of that you should be losing troops out of your camps.  There's only three ways to lose troops:

- Use them in an attack
- Donate the troops to your clanmates
- Manually remove them from the camp

Now, not everything you set to train will actually train - barracks will stop training if the camps are full.  Is it possible that you're setting them to train without making sure you have the capacity to hold them?

Do you perhaps have a bad data connection when these events occur?  Maybe the game doesn't get the command to train the troops?

It's also possible that someone with access to your account or your device is removing the troops from your camp.  Do you have anyone else who has access to your device/account?

Comment: **Is it possible that you're setting them to train without making sure you have the capacity to hold them?**
I train every time with calculation. I know that the barracks will not train after the maximum amount of troops have come in the army camps. (Because it shows for example "Troop capacity after training 50/190")
**Do you perhaps have a bad data connection when these events occur? Maybe the game doesn't get the command to train the troops?**
No I play at a place where there is a very good internet connection. Since I have OCD, I check several times after I have given the training command,

Comment: Cont.
**Do you have anyone else who has access to your device/account?** 
No, no one else uses my account or device because I always change my passcode every week.

Comment: Even after donating or attacking, I quickly come to home and train. I haven't removed any troop manually until now.

Comment: @San97s, those are the only reasons I can think of as to why your troops are missing.  As far as I know, there are no bugs that would cause this to happen, and those are the only reason they'd disappear in the course of a normal game.

Comment: I can understand. I have made a thread on their supercell forum and also have emailed the issue to their support team.

Answer (score 0):

It has not happened to me before.But sometimes,my baby brother likes to get into my account,and do random stuff. The only ways to lose troops is: 1.Donate 2.Attack 3.Delete from camps.Otherwise,something might've happened.

Answer (score 0):

It happened something similar one time for me. I had full camps preparing for clan war attack, and I had got one dragon donated in my castle, but I didn't have time then to attack in the war.

Later that evening, when I was going to attack, all camps were empty, and also the dragon in my clan castle was gone. The only thing I can think of is some glitch because of bad network (I had bad connection when I lost it).